# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in form validation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an issue. I an trying to validate my form and check inputs dor ampty value. It works correct. But when I try to write text in the input, I get th error "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined". I don't understand the matter. Why do I get it? And how can I rid of it?Thank you so much.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { MyButton, ErrorMessage } from '../uikit'
import { FormStyle, InputStyle } from '../constants/styles'
import { LOG_IN } from '../routes'

export class SignIn extends Component {

    state = {
        isValidPasword: true,
        isEqual: true,
        isValidMail: true,
        currentPassword: '',
        textInputEmail: '',
        confirmTextInput: ''
    }

    isValid = () => {
        const {
            isEqual, isValidPasword, isValidMail,
            currentPassword, textInputEmail, confirmTextInput
        } = this.state

        if (textInputEmail == '') {
            return alert("Email is empty!")
        }

        if (!isValidMail) {
            return alert("Email is invalid!")
        }

        if (currentPassword == '') {
            return alert("Password is empty!")
        }

        if (!isValidPasword) {
            return alert("Password is invalid!")
        }

        if (!isEqual) {
            return alert("Passwords aren't matching")
        }

        if (confirmTextInput == '') {
            return alert("'Confirm password' field is empty!")
        }

        this.props.navigation.navigate(LOG_IN)
    }

    isEnoughSymbols = (text) => {
        if (text.trim().length < 8) {
            this.setState({ isValidPasword: false })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ isValidPasword: true })
        }
    }

    isMatch = (text) => {
        if (text != this.state.currentPassword) {
            this.setState({ isEqual: false })
        }
    }

    isMail = (text) => {
        const pattern = /\b[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b/i
        let res = text.search(pattern)

        res == -1 ? this.setState({ isValidMail: false }) : this.setState({ isValidMail: true })
    }

    checkEmptyness = (value) => {
        return !value ? false : true
    }

    render() {
        const { mainContainer, buttons } = FormStyle
        const { container, text } = InputStyle
        const { isValidPasword, isEqual, isValidMail, currentPassword } = this.state

        return (
            <View style={mainContainer}>

                <View style={container}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={text}
                        placeholder={'Email'}
                        onChangeText={(e) => this.setState({ textInputEmail: e.target.value })}
                        onEndEditing={(e) => this.isMail(e.nativeEvent.text)}
                    >
                    </TextInput>
                    {
                        isValidMail ? null : <ErrorMessage errorText={'Invalid email!'} />
                    }
                </View>

                <View style={container}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={text}
                        placeholder={'Password'}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        onChangeText={(e) => this.setState({ currentPassword: e.target.value })}
                        onEndEditing={(e) => this.isEnoughSymbols(e.nativeEvent.text)}
                    >
                    </TextInput>
                    {
                        isValidPasword ? null : <ErrorMessage errorText={'Password must have at least 8 symbols!'} />
                    }
                </View>

                <View style={container}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={text}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        placeholder={'Confirm password'}
                    >
                    </TextInput>
                    {
                        isEqual ? null : <ErrorMessage errorText={'Passwords not matching'} />
                    }
                </View>

                <View style={buttons}>
                    <MyButton
                        name={'confirm'.toUpperCase()}
                        onPress={() => this.isValid()} />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you bound the onChange function like this:
onChangeText={(e) => this.setState({ currentPassword: e.target.value })}

You can directly used like:
onChangeText={(e) => this.setState({ currentPassword: e })}